# Amazon Dynamodb Integration with salesforce by sending http request

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce, amazon-dynamodb

I want to connect to Amazon Dynamodb by sending http request.
I am getting various errors while doing so..

The errors are :
1) Connection refused,  The remote host or network may be down
2) Read time out
3) Invalid Request, Some aspect of the HTTP Request is invalid.

I have also tried it with the help of crypto class.. But, had no luck.. :(
Please help me to find the right way to do the integration.. :(

Comment: post the code you tried.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I have resolved the above errors till now..
But i dont know how to calculate the signature for it..
i am getting the below error "com.amazon.coral.service#InvalidSignatureException","message":"Signature expired: 20120116T175052Z is now earlier than 20130410T101728Z (20130410T103228Z - 15 min.)"

Do you have any idea about how to calculate the signature?